# createEntityManagerFactory is failing randomly

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Now and then it is observed that the createEntityManagerFactory is failing. The stack trace is little confusing for me. Can anybody throw some light on it?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.io.File.list(File.java:1133)
 at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1297)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.init(DirectoryArchive.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.init(DirectoryArchive.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.init(DirectoryArchive.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.init(DirectoryArchive.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.init(DirectoryArchive.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.init(DirectoryArchive.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.<init>(DirectoryArchive.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.DirectoryArchive.<init>(DirectoryArchive.java:54)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.ArchiveFactoryImpl.createArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:89)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.findPersistenceArchives(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:302)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.findPersistenceArchives(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:276)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchives(JPAInitializer.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(JPAInitializer.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
 ....
 ...
 ..
  at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
```

On further tracing i see that this is happening when a new EntityManagerFactory is being created after the close of existing one is failing with the following exceptions:

code:

```
synchronized (factoryLock) {
    if (null != emFactory) {
        if (true == emFactory.isOpen()) {
            try {
                emFactory.close();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        emFactory = null;
    }
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

    properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_DRIVER, jdbcDriver);
    properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_CUSTOMIZER,
            "com.ca.waae.dbaccess.custom.JPASessionCustomizer");
    properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_URL, jdbcUrl);
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_PROPERTY+"REQUEST_KERBEROS_SESSION", "true");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_PROPERTY+"SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME", dbPrincipalName);

    emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
            "JPA", properties);
}
```

Exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1440)
        at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:1469)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.clearStatementCache(DatabaseAccessor.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.disconnect(DatabaseAccessor.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.disconnect(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.disconnect(ServerSession.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.logout(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:931)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.logout(ServerSession.java:776)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.removeSessionFromGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.undeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2850)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.close(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.close(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:287)
        at com.ca.waae.dbaccess.dao.AEConnection.createJpaEntityFactory(AEConnection.java:144)
```

persistent.xml contents are like

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.
com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="JPA">
                <class>com.xx.yy.dbaccess.model.table1</class>
                <class>com.xx.yy.dbaccess.model.table2</class>
                <class>com.xx.yy.dbaccess.model.table3</class>
                <class>com.xx.yy.dbaccess.model.table4</class>
                <class>com.xx.yy.dbaccess.model.table5</class>
<properties>
                <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
                <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true"/>
                <property name="eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names " value="false"/>
                <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
                <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
        </properties>

        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Can you share with us your configuration ?

Comment: Edited to reflect createEntityManagerFactory.

Comment: @Anas  - Please let me know what configuration I should be sharing?

Comment: How do you create your EntityManagerFactory ? share with us the persistence.xml  file ? 
For example : 
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("examplePersistenceUn‌​it"); EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

Comment: Turn on logging and see why the EMF isn't being created. Something is going wrong in creation that causes it to retry endlessly.

Comment: Is any more information required?